# angularjs 1.5 calling a controller inside a component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

Is there any problem in calling a controller element inside a component element?

Something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.bandeja_entrada', [...])
.component('MyComponent', {
    templateUrl: 'my_component/my_component.html',
    controller: 'MyController',
})
.controller('MyController' , [ ... ]);
```

Comment: what is the question, exactly?  you aren't "calling" anything in the code snippet you provided.

Comment: Take a look at the line  "controller: 'MyController'"... there is the calling or referencing from MyComponent to MyController

Comment: this looks like a standard way to declare a component... it's still not really clear what your question is here.

Comment: Did you have any problem? If so please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Claies Its not the standard way to use components because in every documentation i have seen the section of controller uses a function for its definition and not a reference to a controller element...  (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: @georgeawg Ive no problems using it..it works ok, is just that i dont have any documental support for making this kind of usage ie. referencing a controller instead of using a function. I dont know if creating a controller has an overhead in this scenario

Comment: Either syntax is valid, the inline syntax is more common in examples because of its simplicity

Comment: @Claies Thanks a lot dude! im just waiting some hours to accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no Problem with that. In Fact, i personally find it better to define my Component Controller this way, because:

**A.)** Use it in multiple Places

This way you are actually defining an Angular Controller, and therefore its available in the whole Module. So you might will have an use case where you need to use your Controller in several places. With this approach, you can easily use the Controller in multiple places. Once for a component, and maybe once in a "regular" view.

**B.)** File Structure

I really like to separate my Controller/Component definition. So I have a File with the Component definition and its routing stuff, and another for the Controller. If you declare the Controller Function as an Angular Controller, this makes it really clean.

Both ways are perfectly fine, so just pick the one which is more suitable for you!

Comment: Thanks lot dude! im just waiting some more hours to watch more opinions and then accept an answer